# mySQL creating list of summed items

Tags: mysql

I am summing over a table and would like to get an additional column with a list of values the some was not grouped over. So,

```
C1   C2    C3
a     z     1
a     y     2
b     z     4
b     y     2
b     x     3
c     x     4
```

and I would like to do `select c1, sum(c3) as sC3, someMagicFunction(c2) from t group by c1`
so that I get

```
C1   sC3    C3
 a     3   y,z
 b     9 x,y,z
 c     4     x
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: fixed the b row, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the magic function you are looking for is GROUP_CONCAT.
See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/

Comment: yay, it exists. Already saw myself convoluting tables here. nice, saved my day

Answer (score 2):

Use group_concat:

```
select c1, group_concat(c2), sum(c3) from your_table group by c1;

+------+------------------+---------+
| c1   | group_concat(c2) | sum(c3) |
+------+------------------+---------+
| a    | z,y              |       3 |
| b    | z,y,x            |       9 |
| c    | x                |       4 |
+------+------------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
SELECT c1, SUM(c3) sC2, GROUP_CONCAT(c2) sC3 FROM tableName 
GROUP BY c1
```